# Information about incoming transactions for a number of addresses

Tags: json-rpc

For a website I need to watch (read-only) a number of bitcoin addresses (like about 100) and to retrieve information about all incoming transaction (within the last week). I need for each incoming transaction the number of confirmations, the amount send, the time and from which address the transaction came.

Actually blockchain.info looks what I need, but the number of API calls seems to be limited to 1 every 10 secs. Also I do not see how I can read the senders addresses. So I think what I have to look into is JSON RPC and communicate with bitcoin demon. Is this the right direction?

Thanks, Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert here, but it looks like you're on the right track. See:

1. [Bitcoin API (JSON RPC)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29)
2. [API Calls List](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list)

I'm guessing you can use the JSON RPC format to make the calls you need (i.e. "getbalance" and "getaccount" calls).

As for reading the sender's address, perhaps "listtransactions" helps?

Comment: Thanks. It ssems it is indeed possible with the JSON RPC though some things are very difficult to achieve (like checking the balance of an address). For the send addresses one has to get the raw message, decode it and parse the output. Thanks again.